# Convert to ISO time format in Angular using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I'm trying to format date in this below format

> 20230201T103000Z

i tried this method in angular

```
moment(utctime).format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmsssZ')
```

this is returning following date format

```
20230523T1900000+05:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Z' is a token witch will show time zone. You can add your 'Z' as part of string

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```
console.log(moment().format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmss') + 'Z');
```

The second option is Escaping characters using []

```
console.log(moment().format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmss[Z]'));
```